# How to enable connection pooling using Configuration in Resteasy

Tags: java, rest, jersey, resteasy

I'm able to enable connection pooling for **jersey client** in this way:

```
// From org.glassfish.jersey
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 7000);
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 2000);

// From org.apache.http
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
connectionManager.setMaxTotal(100);
connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);

clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, connectionManager);

clientConfig.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
```

How to do the same configuration for Resteasy? I don't want to use the concrete implementation in my code:

```
Client client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
            .connectionPoolSize(100)
            .maxPooledPerRoute(20)
            .connectTimeout(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .readTimeout(7000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build()
```